# Issue with getter and setter with one common variable

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have a task with a temperature converter program. I have to use one veriable in a class what is used by two setter and two getter method.

This is the main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Homero ho = new Homero();
    ho.setCelsius(0);
    System.out.println(ho.getFahrenheit());
    System.out.println(ho.getCelsius());
    ho.setFahrenheit(212);
    System.out.println(ho.getFahrenheit());
    System.out.println(ho.getCelsius());
}
}
```

How can I say to the getters that when the main function set the first setter, the getter return with this... and in the second time return with that...

This is the Homero class:

```
public class Homero {
double celsius;

public void setCelsius(double celsius){
    this.celsius = celsius;
}

public void setFahrenheit(double fahr){
    this.celsius = fahr;
}

public double getFahrenheit(){
        return (this.celsius*9)/5+32;
}


public double getCelsius(){
        return (this.celsius-32)*5/9;
}
}
```

And this would be the proper output:

- 32.0
- 0.0
- 212.0
- 100.0

And the wrong output what I've got.

- 32.0
- -17.77777777777778
- 413.6
- 100.0

Comment: of course this goes wrong. setCelsius(x) and if you then do a getCelcius(), you should get that x, but you calculate it into something else.

Comment: Choose the unit you store. Then convert in the setter and getter of the other unit.

Comment: `this.celsius = fahr;` does not look good. There needs to be a conversion here.

Comment: Yes @Thilo you're right. I didn't understand properly the task. That was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter and setter for celsius does not need a conversion. Do your calculations in the getter and setter for fahrenheit:

```
    public void setCelsius(double celsius){
        this.celsius = celsius;
    }

    public void setFahrenheit(double fahr){
        this.celsius = (fahr -32)*5/9;
    }

    public double getFahrenheit(){
        return this.celsius*9/5+32;
    }


    public double getCelsius(){
        return this.celsius;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. And with your code I finally understand the original task. That was the perfekt solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to reset the other value by the setters, so every time you set a value the other is also new calculated:

```
public static class Homero {
 double celsius;
 double fahrenheit;
 public void setCelsius(double celsius) {
  this.celsius = celsius;
  this.fahrenheit = this.celsius * 1.8 + 32;
 }

 public void setFahrenheit(double fahr) {
  this.fahrenheit = fahr;
  this.celsius = (this.fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
 }

 public double getFahrenheit() {
  return this.fahrenheit;
 }


 public double getCelsius() {
  return this.celsius;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to solve with an extra variable but the solution couldn't come to my mind. This is also good.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setFahrenheit(double fahr){
    this.celsius = fahr;
}
```

this is worng you should convert fahr to cel before assignement.

here :

```
public double getCelsius(){
        return (this.celsius-32)*5/9;
}
```

you should return this.celcius